# Can't android MotionLayout apply Spring animation?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I want to implement Spring animation using MotionLayout.
Also, I want to give stiffness and damping as custom values.

By the way, I saw examples where you need to use the OnSwipe tag to use Spring animation in MotionLayout.

What I want is for animation to work without user's touch.

Is there any way?

Comment: Or am I misunderstanding something?
It's hard to understand because I don't have enough knowledge about animation.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little unclear what you mean by spring animation.
If you want the progress to move in the form of a Spring.
So typically you do:

```kotlin
progress.animateTo(
            1f,
            animationSpec = tween(800)
        )
         MotionLayout(
            ...
            progress = progress.value
        )
```

This can be changed to

```kotlin
    val progress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = 1f,
        animationSpec = spring(
            dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioHighBouncy,
            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMedium
        )
    )
    MotionLayout(
            ...
            progress = progress.value
    )
```

You can achieve spring like effects inside of MotionLayout by creating custom interpolation curves.